# I am getting linking error while compilong opencv4 basic program?

Tags: c++, opencv, dependencies, linker-errors, pacman-package-manager

I installed the OpenCV with the Pacman command. But i am getting hundred of lines of linking error. I compiled my program with the command

```
gcc example.cpp -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

and the small part of the linking error is as follows.

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkRenderingFreeType_AutoInit_Destruct()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorStyle::StartTwoPointer()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorStyle::EndZoom()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(vtkObjectBase*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkOStrStreamWrapper::freeze(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkCamera::SetUserTransform(vtkHomogeneousTransform*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkCommand::UnRegister()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkRenderer::New()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorStyle::StartDolly()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkRenderer::SetActiveCamera(vtkCamera*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorObserver::ReleaseFocus()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkInteractorObserver::ComputeDisplayToWorld(double, double, double, double*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkAlgorithm::Update(vtkInformation*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/../../../../lib/libopencv_viz.so: undefined reference to `vtkMatrix4x4::New()'
```

Comment: i used `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` because there was not opencv.pc file on /usr/pkgconfig/. opencv4.pc file contains the same content as opencv.pc so there is no problem in this file.

Answer (score 2):

opencv libraries themselves are there but `libopencv_viz.so` requires some symbols from the vtk library, which is listed as an [optional dependency](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#optdepends) in opencv's `PKGBUILD`.

You should either just install it yourself (e.g. `pacman -S [--asdeps] vtk`), or complain to `PKGBUILD` maintaintes if you think the dependency should be made non-optional.