# Solved: Create standalone executable for MacOS with OpenCV and libmagic

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, static, c++17

I'm currently trying to compile my program to be standalone.
I'm on a MacOS M2, and the target os is also a MacOS M2. I want to just have to drag and drop the executable from one to another mac and basically run it *without installing anything*...

First of all, I'm not sure that totally possible, and secondly, I'm not really good at these things (compiling correctly, static linking etc.).

I tried to statically compiling OpenCV and libmagic (from "file"), and I don't really know what I did wrong, but I think OpenCV is not correctly built...
Here are the sources I used :

- https://github.com/opencv/opencv  (OpenCV)
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib  (OpenCV Modules)
- https://github.com/file/file  (libmagic is included to file)

**(Edit 1:)**
*The current error* is when I compile using the big g++ command (that you can see lower in this post).
The error in question :
`ld: library not found for -lopencv_viz clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
I checked for sources of viz module (and I can found them).
I correctly include the "include" folder of viz module, so I don't know why it can't found it with -lopencv_viz...

**(Edit 2:)**
I finally find out how to compile to standalone.
First, you will need to build VTK for OpenCV (https://vtk.org/download/).
After that, you will need to build OpenCV (with VTK and Contrib Modules). To do that I used this command :

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -DVTK_DIR=../../VTK-9.3.0/dylibs-build/final-install/usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.3/ -DBUILD_ZLIB=ON -DBUILD_JPEG=ON -DBUILD_PNG=ON -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_WEBP=ON -DBUILD_OPENJPEG=ON -DBUILD_JASPER=ON -DBUILD_OPENEXR=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_JPEG_TURBO_DISABLE=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

Next, you should build libmagic. To do that, I needed to use `autoreconf --install` (I got some issues with autoconf, but not with autoreconf...). After that, just follow "INSTALL" file from the git.
Finally, I bundled all generated libs to a folder at the .cpp root, and I did the same for includes files. So my final compilation command is :

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I./include/libmagic -L./lib/libmagic -lmagic -llzma -lbz2 -lz -I./include/opencv -L./lib/opencv -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -o image_processing image_processing.cpp
```

And finally, I can deliver the program to other MacOS M2 into a .zip file.
**This is not the best way to do that.** But it works, so that ok.
I tried to set "-rpath" on the g++ command, so that could be more efficient, but when I use "otool -l image_processing", every libs are searched by the rpath (path starting with "@rpath") except for the libmagic (and I don't know why...).

Here is the current command I use to compile :
`g++ -std=c++17` pkg-config --static --cflags --libs libmagic pkg-config --static --cflags --libs opencv4 `-o image_indexer image_indexer.cpp`

Which is translate to :
`g++ -std=c++17 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmagic/5.45/include -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmagic/5.45/lib -lmagic -llzma -lbz2 -lz -I/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/include/opencv4 -L/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -o image_indexer image_indexer.cpp`

So there is the program in question :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <magic.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = filesystem;
mutex mtx;

class ThreadPool {
    public:
        ThreadPool( size_t length ) : stop( false ), finishedThreads( 0 ), totalThreads( 0 ) {
            for( size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
                threads.emplace_back( [this] {
                    while( true ) {
                        function<void()> task;
                        {
                            unique_lock<mutex> lock( queueMutex );
                            condition.wait( lock, [this] { return stop || ! tasks.empty(); } );
                            if( stop && tasks.empty() ) return;
                            task = std::move( tasks.front() );
                            tasks.pop();
                        }
                        task();
                        {
                            lock_guard<mutex> lock( counterMutex );
                            ++finishedThreads;
                            if( finishedThreads == totalThreads ) {
                                threadsFinished.notify_one();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
        }
        template<typename F>
        void push( F&& task ) {
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock( queueMutex );
                tasks.push( std::forward<F>( task ) );
            }
            condition.notify_one();
        }
        void waitAll( int total ) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock( counterMutex );
            totalThreads = static_cast<size_t>( total );
            threadsFinished.wait( lock, [this] { return finishedThreads == totalThreads; } );
        }
        ~ThreadPool() {
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock( queueMutex );
                stop = true;
            }
            condition.notify_all();
            for( auto& thread : threads )
                thread.join();
        }
    private:
        vector<thread> threads;
        queue<function<void()>> tasks;
        mutex queueMutex;
        mutex counterMutex;
        condition_variable condition;
        condition_variable threadsFinished;
        size_t finishedThreads;
        size_t totalThreads;
        bool stop;
};

bool isFileReadable( const string& filePath ) {
    try {
        fs::file_status status = fs::status( filePath );
        return fs::is_regular_file( status ) && ( ( status.permissions() & fs::perms::owner_read ) != fs::perms::none );
    } catch( const fs::filesystem_error& e ) {
        cerr << "ERREUR: " << e.what() << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

bool isHiddenFile( const string& filePath ) {
    fs::path path( filePath );
    #ifdef _WIN32
    DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes( path.c_str() );
    if( attributes != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES ) {
        return attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN;
    }
    return false;
    #else
    return ! path.empty() && path.filename().string().front() == '.';
    #endif
}

bool startsWith( const string& input, const string& needle ) {
    return input.substr( 0, needle.size() ) == needle;
}

void writeHTML( const string& content, const string outputFilePath ) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lock( mtx );
    ofstream outputFile( outputFilePath, ios::app );
    if( outputFile.is_open() ) {
        outputFile << content;
        outputFile.close();
    }
}

string base64_encode( const unsigned char* to_encode, unsigned int in_len ) {
    string base64_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    string result;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    unsigned char char_array_3[ 3 ];
    unsigned char char_array_4[ 4 ];
    while( in_len-- ) {
        char_array_3[ i++ ] = *( to_encode++ );
        if( i == 3 ) {
            char_array_4[ 0 ] = ( char_array_3[ 0 ] & 0xFC ) >> 2;
            char_array_4[ 1 ] = (( char_array_3[ 0 ] & 0x03 ) << 4 ) + ( ( char_array_3[ 1 ] & 0xF0 ) >> 4 );
            char_array_4[ 2 ] = (( char_array_3[ 1 ] & 0x0F ) << 2 ) + ( ( char_array_3[ 2 ] & 0xC0 ) >> 6 );
            char_array_4[ 3 ] = char_array_3[ 2 ] & 0x3F;
            for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
                result += base64_chars[ char_array_4[ i ] ];
            }
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if( i ) {
        for( j = i; j < 3; j++ ) {
            char_array_3[ j ] = '\0';
        }
        char_array_4[ 0 ] = ( char_array_3[ 0 ] & 0xFC ) >> 2;
        char_array_4[ 1 ] = ( ( char_array_3[ 0 ] & 0x03 ) << 4 ) + ( ( char_array_3[ 1 ] & 0xF0 ) >> 4 );
        char_array_4[ 0 ] = ( ( char_array_3[ 1 ] & 0x0F ) << 2 ) + ( ( char_array_3[ 2 ] & 0xC0 ) >> 6 );
        char_array_4[ 0 ] = char_array_3[ 2 ] & 0x3F;
        for( j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) {
            result += base64_chars[ char_array_4[ j ] ];
        }
        while( i++ < 3 ) {
            result += '=';
        }
    }
    return result;
}

cv::Mat resizeImage( const cv::Mat& image, const int& width, const int& height ) {
    cv::Mat resized;
    cv::resize( image, resized, cv::Size( width, height ), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA );
    return resized;
}

string encodeToBase64( const cv::Mat& image ) {
    vector<uchar> buffer;
    cv::imencode( ".jpg", image, buffer );
    return base64_encode( buffer.data(), buffer.size() );
}

string getFileMime( const string& filePath ) {
    magic_t magicCookie = magic_open( MAGIC_MIME_TYPE );
    if( magicCookie == NULL ) {
        return "unknown";
    }
    magic_load( magicCookie, NULL );
    const char* mimeType = magic_file( magicCookie, filePath.c_str() );
    string mimeTypeString = mimeType ? mimeType : "unknown";
    magic_close( magicCookie );
    return mimeTypeString;
}

void processImage( const string outputFile, const string& filePath, const int& width, const int& height, bool verbose=false ) {
    if( ! isFileReadable( filePath ) ) return;
    fs::directory_entry fileEntry( filePath );
    string mime = getFileMime( filePath );
    string fileName = fileEntry.path().filename().string();
    if( startsWith( mime, "image/" ) ) {
        cv::Mat image = cv::imread( filePath );
        if( ! image.empty() ) {
            cv::Mat resizedImage = resizeImage( image, width, height );
            string base64Data = encodeToBase64( resizedImage );
            string tempContent = R"(
    <div style="position: relative;">
            )";
            tempContent += "<img src=\"data:" + mime + ";base64," + base64Data + "\" alt=\"" + fileName + "\" title=\"" + fileName + "\" />";
            tempContent += R"(
        <div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 0;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;width: 100%;height: fit-content;padding-block: 1rem;padding-inline: .75rem;background: rgba(255 255 255 / .5);">
            <span>Nom : )";
            tempContent += fileName;
            tempContent += R"(</span>
        </div>
    </div>
            )";
            writeHTML( tempContent, outputFile );
            if( verbose ) cout << "Image actuelle : " << filePath << endl;
        }
    }
}

int processImagesInFolder( const string outputFile, ThreadPool& threadPool, const string& folderPath, const int& width, const int& height, bool verbose=false, int count=0 ) {
    vector<string> filePaths;
    vector<thread> threads;
    try {
        for( const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator( folderPath ) ) {
            if( fs::is_regular_file( entry ) && ! isHiddenFile( entry.path().string() ) ) {
                string filePath = entry.path().string();
                ++count;
                threadPool.push( [=]() {
                    processImage( outputFile, filePath, width, height, verbose );
                } );
            } else if( fs::is_directory( entry ) && ! isHiddenFile( entry.path().string() ) ) {
                count += processImagesInFolder( outputFile, threadPool, fs::canonical( entry.path() ).string(), width, height, verbose, count );
            }
        }
    } catch( fs::filesystem_error e ) {
        cerr << "HANDLING: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return count;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    unordered_map<string, string> args;
    for( int i = 0; i < argc; ++i ) {
        string argument = argv[ i ];
        if( argument.substr( 0, 2 ) == "--" ) {
            size_t position = argument.find( '=' );
            if( position != string::npos ) {
                string key = argument.substr( 2, position - 2 );
                string value = argument.substr( position + 1 );
                args[ key ] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    int width = 300;
    int height = 250;
    int threadsCount = 10;
    bool verbose = false;
    string filePath = "./";
    string filename = "index.html";
    if( args.count( "width" ) ) {
        width = stoi( args[ "width" ] );
    }
    if( args.count( "height" ) ) {
        height = stoi( args[ "height" ] );
    }
    if(
        args.count( "verbose" ) &&
        (
            args[ "verbose" ] == "true" ||
            args[ "verbose" ] == "yes" ||
            args[ "verbose" ] == "1" ||
            args[ "verbose" ] == "y"
        )
    ) {
        verbose = true;
    }
    if( args.count( "threads") ) {
        threadsCount = stoi( args[ "threads" ] );
    }
    if( args.count( "outFolder" ) ) {
        filePath = args[ "outFolder" ];
    }
    if( args.count( "outFilename" ) ) {
        filename = args[ "outFilename" ];
    }
    if( args.count( "folder" ) ) {
        cout << "L'indexation peut prendre un certain temps...." << endl;
        ThreadPool threadPool( static_cast<size_t>( threadsCount ) );
        string finalHTML = R"(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Indexation photo</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(31 41 55);">
    <div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: space-around;gap: 1.5rem;padding-block: 1rem;padding-inline: 2.5rem;">)";
        if( filePath.back() != '/' ) filePath += '/';
        ofstream outputFile( filePath + filename );
        if( outputFile.is_open() ) {
            outputFile << finalHTML;
            outputFile.close();
        }
        string folderPath = args[ "folder" ];
        int total = processImagesInFolder( filePath + filename, threadPool, folderPath, width, height, verbose );
        if( verbose ) cout << total <<" fichiers à traiter." << endl;
        threadPool.waitAll( total );
        finalHTML = R"(
    </div>
</body>
</html>)";
        writeHTML( finalHTML, filePath + filename );
        cout << endl << "Fichier index.html généré avec succès.\nIl répertori les images du dossier : " << folderPath << endl;
        return 0;
    } else {
        cout << "Pour utiliser cet indexeur, veuillez préciser au moins l'argument 'folder'" << endl;
        cout << "--> Utilisation: ./image_indexer --folder=/Users/name/Pictures" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Arguments :" << endl;
        cout << "--folder: Permet de préciser le dossier a indexer" << endl;
        cout << "--width: Précise la longueur en pixel de l'image retaillée" << endl;
        cout << "--height: Précise la hauteur en pixel de l'image retaillée" << endl;
        cout << "--verbose: Affiche l'image actuellement traitée (préciser 'y'/'yes'/'1')" << endl;
        cout << "--threads: Nombre de threads en simulatané (défaut: 10)" << endl;
        cout << "--outFolder: Chemin du dossier de génération" << endl;
        cout << "--outFilename: Nom du fichier HTML généré" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I tried to compile OpenCV and libmagic statically. I think no problems with libmagic (no errors etc), but for OpenCV it's another history...

I used this command to build OpenCV with modules :
`mkdir build && cd build && cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ../opencv/ && make -j8`
This take a while to build.

After that, I just basically tried to link all required libraries to the G++ command.
That give me something like that (*I replaced all absolute path*) :

```
g++ -std=c++17 -lbz2 -lz -o image_processing image_processing.cpp \
-I/content/opencv/modules/core/include \
-I/content/file/src \
-I/content/opencv4/opencv/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/features2d/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/calib3d/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/core/include \
-I/content/opencv4/build \
-I/content/opencv/modules/flann/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/dnn/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/highgui/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/videoio/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/imgproc/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/gapi/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/ml/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/objdetect/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/photo/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/stitching/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/video/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/shape/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/superres/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/videostab/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/aruco/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/bgsegm/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/bioinspired/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/ccalib/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/datasets/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/dpm/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/face/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/freetype/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/fuzzy/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/hdf/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/line_descriptor/include \
-I/content/opencv/modules/optflow/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/video/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/plot/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/reg/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/saliency/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/stereo/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/structured_light/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/phase_unwrapping/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/rgbd/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/viz/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/surface_matching/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/text/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/xobjdetect/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/xphoto/include \
-I/content/modules/opencv_contrib/modules/xobjdetect/include \
-L/content/modules/build/lib \
-L/content/file/src/.libs \
-lopencv_shape \
-lopencv_stitching \
-lopencv_superres \
-lopencv_videostab \
-lopencv_aruco \
-lopencv_bgsegm \
-lopencv_bioinspired \
-lopencv_ccalib \
-lopencv_datasets \
-lopencv_dpm \
-lopencv_face \
-lopencv_freetype \
-lopencv_fuzzy \
-lopencv_hdf \
-lopencv_line_descriptor \
-lopencv_optflow \
-lopencv_video \
-lopencv_plot \
-lopencv_reg \
-lopencv_saliency \
-lopencv_stereo \
-lopencv_structured_light \
-lopencv_phase_unwrapping \
-lopencv_rgbd \
-lopencv_viz \
-lopencv_surface_matching \
-lopencv_text \
-lopencv_ximgproc \
-lopencv_calib3d \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_flann \
-lopencv_xobjdetect \
-lopencv_objdetect \
-lopencv_ml \
-lopencv_xphoto \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_videoio \
-lopencv_imgcodecs \
-lopencv_photo \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_core
```

Comment: There's a lot of useful detail in your question, but you've failed to say what goes wrong when you try all of this. Compile error? Link error? Runtime error? Error messages?

Comment: Oh yeah your true !... The current problem when I use the big g++ command is :
ld: library not found for -lopencv_viz
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: OK well you've provided a couple of `-L` options to tell the linker where to look for libraries. The next task is to look in those locations for a file called `libopencv_viz.a` (or something) and see if it's there.

Comment: If this is the only missing library then I would just remove it. But if you think you really need it for some reason, then this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559925/how-do-i-use-install-viz-in-opencv) might help.

Comment: How... You right, there is no libopencv_viz.a... I can found all other (didn't checked all one by one). But that strange to me, because I didn't got any error when compiling OpenCV (with modules). So what could I do now ? Just re-build everything ?

Comment: @john In fact, I can't totally tell you if Viz is required or not. Because when I remove -I for viz, and -lopencv_viz, I got `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`. The error message is containing a lot of informations on referenced symbols not found. And I don't really know if there are linked to viz. Examples : `_TIFFClientOpen`, `Imf_3_2::Header::channels()`, `_clEnqueueMarker`, `_png_set_strip_16`... Finally, I don't see any ref to libopencv_viz (most of the time the ref come from libopencv_imgcodecs.a and libopencv_core.a)

Comment: If you read that link I provided it seems that building opencv_viz requires an extra library and some additional build options.

Comment: OK that latest error suggests that you are building for the wrong architecture, arm64 and x64 are the two options I believe. This is getting outside of my expertise however, I'm not a Mac guy.

Comment: Same thing is explained there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150527/i-am-getting-linking-error-while-compilong-opencv4-basic-program did you search for the (seemingly common) issue at all?

Comment: @ÖöTiib In fact, I'm not really the most comfortable with C++... I tried to search, but I found nothing. And by the way, I didn't know chat should be my Google Search for this issue... But thanks for the link, I will dig in

Comment: @john Yeah this issue for the wrong architecture is really strange to me... I compile everything on the same OS (MacOS M2), with options really close. So I think I just gonna skip the arch issue for now (because I already had this error when compiling with a malformed command, and the error is just gone after re-written the command), to handle VTK (that I should compile statically also I suppose)

Comment: If toolset tells you that opencv_viz is missing then type to google "opencv_viz  missing" google spits you whole page of links to same story that it depends on VTK that you need to build as well.

Comment: @ÖöTiib That’s what I would have done if I had understood that she was missing... As I said, I'm not too comfy with C++, G++ and how lib etc works.
I found those links [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/99506/how-to-install-opencv-with-vtk-for-viz/) which is on Windows, but gave me informations on how to compile with VTK ([link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/227761/opencv-viz-module-unavailable-cmake-windows-10/) this one also helps)

Comment: What, exactly, are the requirements and the degrees of freedom here? Are you allowed to package everything into a Docker container? That would allow you to use the well-trodden path of dynamic linking everything while still hiding the implementation details from the users.

Comment: @Botje Unfortunately, I can't have Docker... That is the best quickiest and easiest option I think, but the first requirement is : Not install anything, this program should be used on other MacOS M2. (not aimed to be used on Windows or Linux, just on very similarly systems).
That also why I'm not sur if this is really possible... In fact if it is not, please tell me.

Comment: Is shipping your binary with a bunch of .dylibs and an option? That is how application bundles work, after all. Again, static linking is painful.

Comment: @Botje That is a very good option ! And I tried lol (but as I said on the post, "I don't really know what I did wrong"). So my first option was to try with .dylibs, and I failed. So I suppose I did something wrong, but what ?
Because as you said, this could be a package instead of just an executable.

**Edit:** If you have some steps to follow to compile OpenCV, OpenCV Modules, VTK and libmagic to get .dylibs (I suppose that similarly commands), and how to compile the cpp with those dylibs ? That would be really nice

Comment: @Kum0 If you've solved the problem, you should post an answer to your question instead of editing your question to contain the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks @user12002570 (I'm not used posting on stack overflow, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out how to compile to standalone.

**This is not a really good solution** because it's only aimed to be shared with other MacOS M2, and there is other ways to do this better.

So first, you will need to build VTK for OpenCV (https://vtk.org/download/).

After that, you will need to build OpenCV, with VTK and Contrib Modules.
To do it, I used this command :

```
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -DVTK_DIR=../../VTK-9.3.0/dylibs-build/final-install/usr/local/lib/cmake/vtk-9.3/ -DBUILD_ZLIB=ON -DBUILD_JPEG=ON -DBUILD_PNG=ON -DBUILD_TIFF=ON -DBUILD_WEBP=ON -DBUILD_OPENJPEG=ON -DBUILD_JASPER=ON -DBUILD_OPENEXR=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_JPEG_TURBO_DISABLE=ON -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ..
```

Next, you need to build libmagic. To do that, you should follow instructions from the github.

In my case, I needed to use `autoreconf --install` instead of `autoconf`. (I got some issues with autoconf, but not with autoreconf...).

Finally, I bundled all generated libs, and all included files to a folder at the root of the program.

Then I built the program using this command :

```
g++ -std=c++17 -I./include/libmagic -L./lib/libmagic -lmagic -llzma -lbz2 -lz -I./include/opencv -L./lib/opencv -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -o image_processing image_processing.cpp
```

As I said, this is not the best way to do it (I suppose).
And I tried to use the "rpath" option from g++, but for some reason, I can't make it work for libmagic. (To check, I used `otool -l image_processing`, and every lib paths starts with "@rpath", except for those from libmagic)

(Thanks @Botje and @user12002570)